# MapBox-GL query point on mobile

Tags: mapbox-gl

On a mobile device, when clicking on points to get info, it randomly appears.

```
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ['stations']
      });
```

I guess it is a matter of coordinates precision (it is more precise on web, when using the mouse), so instead of normal queryRenderedFeatures I apply the query by bounding box

```
  const bbox = [
        [e.point.x - 5, e.point.y - 10],
        [e.point.x + 5, e.point.y + 10]
        ];
        // Find features intersecting the bounding box.
  const selectedFeatures = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {
        layers: ['stations']
        });

   if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) 
          var feature = selectedFeatures[0];            
        else
          var feature = selectedFeatures
```

But even searching inside these extra 10px, most of the times I get no feature. It is not that the circles are very small...
Which would be the approach for mobile?